# How can I open multiple csv files in a folder, take the average of a column and save in a separate file using python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I am extremely new at python and need some help with this one. I've tried various codes and none seem to work, so suggestions would be awesome.

I have a folder with about 1500 csv files that each contain multiple columns of data. I need to take the average of the first column called "agr" and save this value in a different excel or csv file. It would be great if I could also somehow save the name of the file with its averaged value so that I can keep track of which file it came from. The name of the files are crop_city (e.g. corn_omaha).

```
import glob
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


path = ('C:/test/*.csv')

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open(fname) as csvfile:
        agr = []
        reader = csv.DictReader(fname)
        print row['agr']
```

I know the code above is extremely rudimentary, so any help would be great thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you add a few line example of the input file and what you want the output to look like? Is that first column a decimal number? What separator is used between columns?

Comment: The input file is a comma delimited file (csv) and it is a float value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the answer by @tdelaney, I would not advise you to limit your code by relying on the fact that you are adding up the first column; what if you need to work with the third column next week? It's easy to do this properly by building on the code you provide. Parsing a couple of thousand text files is not going to slow you down.

The `csv.DictReader` constructor will automatically treat the first row of its input as a header (unless you explicitly specify a list of column names with the `fieldnames` parameter). So your code can look like this:

```
import csv
import glob

averages = []
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open(fname, "rb") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        values = [ float(row["agr"]) for row in reader ]
        avg = sum(values) / len(values)
        averages.append((fname, avg))
```

The list `averages` now contains the numbers you want. This is how you write it out to another CSV file:

```
with open("avegages.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["File", "Average agr"])
    for row in averages:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

PS. Since you included `pandas` in your imports, here's one way to do the same thing with pandas. However, I recommend sticking with `csv` for now. The `pandas` object model is complex, and hard to wrap your head around.

```
averages = []
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(fname)
    averages.append((fname, data["agr"].mean()))

df_out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(averages, columns=["File", "Average agr"])
df_out.to_csv("averages.csv", index=False)
```

As you can see the code is a lot shorter, since file i/o and calculations can be done with one statement.

Comment: One quick question.. it is giving me an error about converting a string to float which I am assuming is that it is trying to convert the first row of headers in the csv files from a string to a float, is there a way around this?

Comment: Don't assume, test! Print some diagnostics and find the row that's giving you the problem. As I wrote in my answer, the first row is interpreted as the column names, so that can't be it. You probably have a row that's missing a value for the first column, since a `ValueError` will normally show you the string that cannot be converted to a float. Maybe it's something silly like a blank line or an extra newline at the end of the csv file...

Comment: PS. I just noticed you are using Python 2. Do yourself a favor and switch to Python 3 today! Unless you **have** to use some library that hasn't been ported to Python 3.

Comment: Ah I was able to figure it out. Some of the csv files have a blank cell when the data coming from a webservice could not be pulled (e.g. if there was no data for that year, the entire row except the 'year' column is blank) which I believe is throwing the string to float error. I'm assuming I will have to use an option for if a cell is blank.. would you be able to help with this too? Thanks so much, you are a lifesaver.

Comment: Assuming you want to just skip such rows, try this: `values = [ float(row["agr"]) for row in reader if row["agr"] != "" ]`.

Comment: Perfect! This makes total sense now, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first column in these CSV files is a decimal or float, you don't really need to parse the entire line. Just split at the first separator and parse the first token. There is no real advantage to `numpy` or `pandas` either. Just use the builtin `sum` function.

```
import glob
import os

path = ('test/*.csv') # using local dir for test
outfile.write("Filename,Sum\r\n") # header for output
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    for fname in glob.glob(path):
        with open(fname) as csvfile:
            next(csvfile) # skip header
            outfile.writelines("{},{}\r\n".format(os.path.basename(fname), 
                sum(float(line.split(',', 1)[0].strip()) 
                for line in csvfile)))
```

Comment: Also, one quick addition is that the csv input files have string headers, so those may need to be dealt with differently?